# Loading data from database to combo box using another thread

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, multithreading

I want to add items in combo box after getting a column from database table. To achieve performance I have placed this task in a newly created thread

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString());
}
```

but it gives the following exception:

*"Cross thread operation not valid"*

I searched for it and tried to solve this problem with the help of different methods, delegates. I tried to pass the whole dataTable to another method but couldn't solve the problem.

Please tell me how do I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Simply wrap the code in a delegate passed to `BeginInvoke`:

```
comboBox.BeginInvoke(
    (Action)(() =>
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
          comboBox.Items.Add(dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString());
       }
    }));
```

This way you are forwarding the updates to the GUI thread, because it's the only thread allowed to make changes on the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can ( and probably should ) run the database query on a background thread, but you must update UI controls on the UI thread. That's just the way Windows works.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread is not the UI thread. Only the UI thread can access to the UI controls like your combobox
So your method to update the combobox items should check if it's called from the UI thread and (if not) switch to that before trying to use the combobox .

```
public delegate void OnAddTable(DataTable dataTable);

private void AddTable(DataTable dataTable)
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired) 
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new OnAddTable(AddTable), new object[] {dataTable}));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++) 
    { 
        comboBox.Items.Add(dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString()); 
    }
}
```